# live object detection with yolo3

Tags: python, opencv, keras, yolo

good evening guys, i would like to implement live object detection with yolo3 model, here is  following code  which i have implemented during class :

```
from keras.models import load_model
from yolo3 import *
import yolo3
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.utils import load_img,img_to_array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mymodel =load_model("coco_yolo3.h5")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # Read one frame from the videofile
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite("Test.jpg",frame)
    # Do the lane Detection
    # Display the frame with drawn lanes
    # cv2.imshow('human', frame)
    # Quit program if q is pressed. cv.waitkey(1) is needed to display something with OpenCV
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    image = plt.imread("Test.jpg")
    width, height = image.shape[1], image.shape[0]
    print(width, height)
    # print(mymodel.summary())
    x = load_img("Test.jpg", target_size=(YOLO3.width, YOLO3.height))
    x = img_to_array(x) / 255.0
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    y = mymodel.predict(x)
    boxes = decode_predictions(y, width, height, min_score=0.7)
    draw_boxes("Test.jpg", boxes)
    plt.show()

# Close the videofile
cap.release()
# Close all OpenCV windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()




# plt.show()
```

here what i am trying is to save every frame , then read it and draw on read image, how can i  do so that  it should  print  result on  live  stream? on frame?i think it need just simple change, here is additional  code for draw_boxes if you like :

```
def draw_boxes(filename, boxes, figsize=(12, 8)):
    image = plt.imread(filename)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize, subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})
    ax.imshow(image)

    for box in boxes:
        y1, x1, y2, x2 = box.ymin, box.xmin, box.ymax, box.xmax
        width, height = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
        rect = Rectangle((x1, y1), width, height, fill=False, color='red', lw=2)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        label = f'{box.label} ({box.score:.0%})'
        ax.text(x1 + (width / 2), y1, label, color='white', backgroundcolor='red', ha='center', va='bottom', fontweight='bold', bbox=dict(color='red'))
```

i think we can update code and  if given frame  is already   presented like in this  code :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # Read one frame from the videofile
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

it should apply  directly right?